# When click on button to change data-value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, thymeleaf

I have a hyperlink which have to change direction of sorting.

```
<a href="#" id="sort-newest" th:attr="data-value=${sortdir}">Newest</a>
```

When click on the link, I want to change data-value whithout refresh page.

```
$('#sort-newest').click(function(event){
    var url = [[${url_current}]];
    var sortby = 'isNew';
    var sortdir = $(this).attr('data-value');

    if (sortdir == 'ASC') {
        sortdir = 'DESC';
    } else if(sortdir == 'DESC') {
        sortdir == 'ASC';
    }

    var data = {
        sortby: sortby,
        sortdir: sortdir
    };

    $('#productList').load(url, data);
});
```

This is not working and I can not understand why. Can you help me please ?

Comment: I couldn't see anywhere in your code that is changing data value...

Comment: Remove the comma after "sortdir" in the data array.

Comment: what's not working exactly...

Comment: Where did you see comma after "sortdir" in the data array ?

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are using jQuery

```
 var sortdir = $(this).attr('data-value');
```

for the above code to work you must have

`data-value="${sortdir}"` not `th:attr="data-value=${sortdir}"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" data-value="10">
```

If u want to change the data value using jquery

```
$("element").data("value") = "25";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid attribute.

Change `th:attr="data-value=${sortdir}"` to `data-value="${sortdir}"`.

```
<a href="#" id="sort-newest" data-value="${sortdir}">Newest</a>
```

Use the `.attr()` jQuery function to set/update the attribute:

```
$('#sort-newest').attr('data-value', 'new value');
```

Comment: $('#sort-newest').attr('data-value', 'new value');
It works but I want when I click second time to change again.
Example the value is "DESC", when I click the value is changed "ASC", when click second time the value is changed again to "DESC".